# Extend the search bar of Yammer with custom API

Tags: yammer

I would like to link my search engine with the Yammer search bar.

For example, when a user search something in the Yammer search bar, the yammer search bar can search into my search engine and return to the user all results.

Thanks you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to do this. Your only option would be to build a browser extension that hooked into the Yammer UI, but it'd be brittle because the Yammer site is always changing, and you'd have to keep up.